# mysqli bind() variables initialize beforehand

Tags: php, mysqli

I came across this tutorial 
http://www.xphp.info/mysqli-tutorial/
and the following was written: Pick your variables and initialize them beforehand:

```
$rowId = 0;
$rowFirstName = '';
$rowLastName = '';
$rowAge = 0;
$statement->bind_result($rowId,$rowFirstName,$rowLastName,$rowAge);
```

Is there a difference between initializing beforehand like in the example and just bind_result without initializing ?

```
$statement->bind_result($rowId,$rowFirstName,$rowLastName,$rowAge);
```

Comment: Yeah - if they don't get set from the result of your query then they will remain undefined when you try to use them later.

Comment: Pretty nice tutorial considering its age. I always assume the worst when SO questions start out with *"I'm following this tutorial (written 2+ years ago)..."*

Comment: @scrowlertypically this may be correct, but typical result sets from query will define the variable and assign it to null at best. At worst throw a notice/error/warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question... no. There is no difference as passing the variables by reference (as they are in `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()` implicitly defines them.

Consider this simple example...

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(&$foo) { }
}

$foo = new Foo($bar);

var_dump(get_defined_vars());
// amongst all the noise, you will find "bar" with value NULL
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/203850